# change softkeyboard layout with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

I am looking for examples of how to customise the layout of the softkeyboard that is displayed within a website when a textbox is selected. I can find examples of doing it for a fully fledged android app but not within a website.

I am looking to be able to not display the smiley or the number/special character key when the softkeyboard opens.

Answer (score 0):

1. See if you can right click on the softkeyboard element in the browser.
2. If so click on inspect element and see if you can find the element that contains the smiley or the
   number/special character key.
3. Then you can construct a script to hide it or remove it when the page loads.
4. Using JQuery it might look something like this:

   ```
   //note: You must place this code in a script tag after you have loaded JQuery.

   $(document).ready(function(){//begin document ready function

   //store the id or the class of the key to hide
   var key = $("#nameOfKeyID");

   //hide the key
   $(key).hide();

   //or remove the key
    //this will remove it from the page
     //and you will not be able to perform operations on it
    $(key).remove();




    });//end document ready function
   ```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately I can't get the element. I would have thought there was an easy way to modify the layout programatically!